# How to expand setOnMarkerClickListener of OSMbonuspacket Marker without overriding default behavior?

Tags: android, onclicklistener, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am working on an app that makes use of the **OSMbonuspacket**. I added markers with descriptions to the map. When clicking one of the markers, the description box is shown.

Now I want to call another function when tapping on a marker. Let's say I want to show a Toast. So I added the following `setOnMarkerClickListener()` function:

```
marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

This shows the Toast when clicking the marker. However, the description box is not displayed anymore. I guess that I am overriding the default behavior.  with this function. I made an app with a Google Maps integration once and did the same thing without any problems.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this with the OSMbonuspacket?

Comment: Try return super.OnMarkerClick(marker, mapview)

Comment: @spy, thanks for your suggestion. I tried returning `super.onMarkerClick(marker, mapView);` instead of `false` in my  `inMarkerClick(...)` function. That's what you meant right? But the compiler says that this function doesn't exist :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default click listener for Marker in osmdroid look like this:

```
protected boolean onMarkerClickDefault(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    if(marker.mPanToView) {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(marker.getPosition());
    }

    return true;
}
```

so, you can override your listener like this:

```
marker.setOnMarkerClickListener(new Marker.OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker, MapView mapView) {
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        mapView.getController().animateTo(marker.getPosition());
        Toast.makeText(context, "Hallo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```